# How to move (translate animation) a button with clickable area?

Tags: android, animation

I'm moving a button to fade when scrolls, but when animating, the clickable area not moving! How I must move this button completely to new position?

[image: animation]

here is my code:

```
mBtnCompare.animate().translationY(15).alpha(0).setDuration(200);
```

and here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".acts.ActProductDetail">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/actDet_Scrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ... //some elements

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
    android:id="@+id/actMain_btnCompare"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/fab_transformation_sheet_behavior"
    fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/white"
    fancy:fb_borderWidth="3dp"
    fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fancy:fb_radius="25dp"
    fancy:fb_text="مقایسه محصول"
    fancy:fb_textColor="@color/white"
    fancy:fb_textGravity="center"
    fancy:fb_textSize="@dimen/sub_text_size" /></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean that when the button fades it's still clickable? If that's the case, apply  an animation listener to the button, and on animation end call setEnabled(false) to the button

Comment: @NikosHidalgo yes, I know that. I want to do it in a right way. thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by moving to new position? if you want to invisible it completely, you should set its visibility to invisible

Comment: @PouyaHeydari I want to hide it with animation as shown in question (if you dont see gif, plz turn on your proxy :) ).

Comment: yea I can see the photo :D actually there are only 2 ways. hiding it by using setVisibility in onAnimationEnd or translating your button out of the screen completely. (translationY = 1000)

Comment: even with (translationY = 1000), the clickable area remains in old position and click on it is working yet.

Comment: can you post your xml code?

Comment: what do you mean by "do it in a right way"?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I mean translate a view with moving clickable area, instead of move a view and disable onClick to prevent click action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
mBtnCompare.animate().translationY(150);
```

instead of:

```
mBtnCompare.animate().translationY(15);
```

`setOnClickListener` will work as you expect when u use a bigger value.

Comment: The only different between translationY(float a) and translationYBy(float b) is that first one moves view to exactly 'a' position vertically, but in second one, moves the view to oldY + 'b'

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi actually if you choose a big float b to push your view out of screen, your view wont be clickable. thats the exact difference

Comment: You were correct. after increasing the argument the problem solved. please update your answer. Then I accept it. thanks